# Request permission for speech recognition iOS, Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to ask the user for permissions to use the speech recognition.

Actually the button "Get Permissions" always appear. The button should only appear, if the app after starting listen() has no permissions. Thank you for a hint.

**HTML**

```
<button ion-button full (click)="getPermission()" *ngIf="requestPermission">Get Permissions</button>
<button ion-button full (click)="listen()" color="{{buttonColor}}">
```

**home.ts**

```
async hasPermission():Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      const permission = await this.speech.hasPermission();
      return permission;    
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async getPermission():Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.speech.requestPermission();
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  listen(): void {.......}
```